# How do I do declare relationship on flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

> I have two tables I want to link. 
>   **Teams** 
>
>   -id 
>   -name 
>   
>   **Event** 
>
>   -id 
>   -t1 
>   -t2 
>   -date

Now how do I create a relationship if I want to get team name (t1.name, t2.name) when I try to get all the events based on date range? Did I declare the relationship correctly?

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app import app, db

class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    teams_event = relationship('Team', secondary=Event.__tablename__, primaryjoin=id == Event.t1, secondaryjoin=id == Event.t2, lazy='dynamic')

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    t1 = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Team.id'))
    t2 = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('Team.id'))
```

Comment: It may be worth posting a stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: I think in your case it's better to use ManyToMany relationship. It will be much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a solution to my problem. I can now get the team information for every event.

**I replaced this relationship**

```
teams_event = relationship('Team', secondary=Event.__tablename__, primaryjoin=id == Event.t1, secondaryjoin=id == Event.t2, lazy='dynamic')
```

**With the following:**

```
t1_teams = relationship('Team', primaryjoin=('Event.t1 == Team.id'))
t2_teams = relationship('Team', primaryjoin=('Event.t2 == Team.id'))
```